# What's the name of the business group within a company that organizes events, trade shows, goodies, etc.?

Tags: title

As this is something I would like to work in at some point in the future (and have done it a few times on my own initiative), I was wondering what type of roles or business functions (departments or groups) usually do this within a larger corporation/organization?

What is the exact name of the process?

I guess "marketing" and "promotions" are too generic. Are they a subset of those functions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "name that thing" question. "Name that thing" are bad questions for the same reasons that "identify this obscure TV show, film or book by its characters or story" are bad questions: you can't Google them, they aren't practical in any way, they don't help anyone else, and allowing them opens the door for the asking of other types of marginal questions. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game

Answer (score 3):

Public Relations would be the general name for the department in big companies that handle press releases, TV appearances, trade show presentations, etc. In some companies this is part of Corporate Communications which is usually part of marketing or HR depending on the company.

There may be companies that organize trade shows or provide marketing materials that make operations possibly part of things here.